Using Twilio initiate a basic yes/no question using data from my web app
We are currently using Twilio to text out basic alerts to myself and my boss when something critical happens in our web app.  Now I'd like to take it a step further.
I'm thinking I need to use Twilio's Conversation feature for this, but maybe there is a simpler less complicated route?  When a specific action happens in my web app (NodeJS) I want to trigger a question to be texted out to myself and maybe my boss.  That question will need to have specific data generated from the web app.  Then if it receives a 'yes', I want it to call a specific webhook and if 'no', just do nothing.  So it seems like Conversations is what I'm looking for, but also that kinda seems like overkill for this simple use case.

You can, but don't have to, use conversations for this. The regular messaging API would work too. Or you could even use Studio to build a flow that is trigger via a REST API call

OK, I guess my question then is if I don't use Conversations, how will Twilio know the incoming "yes" text is in reply to the question that went out or if it is just a random "yes" text that comes in?

If you want to use regular messaging, you'd need to do the state management on your own. I understand that this can be tricky. Studio would be the ideal and most simple way to achieve this.
